# Sort a multi dimensional array with dates as keys in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have already converted the dates into an array of Unix timestamps as shown below.

```
Array
(
    [ONE] => Array
        (
            [1460581200] => 
            [1460667600] => 
            [0] => 
        )

    [TWO] => Array
        (
            [1465506000] => 
            [1468184400] => 
            [0] => 
            [1470949200] => 
        )

)
```

I would like to arrange the dates inside this array so that they can be in a descending order without affecting the primary array keys.

I also would like the [0] (which indicates that the date is not present) to be on top.

Comment: Have you tried something? It's a simple problem, PHP provides a lot of support for [array sorting](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php).

Comment: i had previously tried using ksort and array_multisort. Both did not work as I would have liked. [aslawin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3233344/aslawin) answer worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php

$array = Array
(
    'ONE' => Array
        (
            '1460581200' => 'aaa',
            '1460667600' => 'bbb',
            '0' => 'ccc',
        ),
    'TWO' => Array
        (
            '1465506000' => 'ddd',
            '1468184400' => 'eee',
            '0' => 'fff',
            '1470949200' => 'ggg',
        )
);


function sortByKeys($array)
{
    $result = array();
    if(isset($array[0]))
    {
        $result[0] = $array[0];
        unset($array[0]);
    }

    krsort($array);

    return $result + $array;
}

$result = array_map('sortByKeys',$array);

print_r($result);
```

[**Working example**](https://eval.in/569417)